# Properties of wood in furniture

Tags: everyday-chemistry, materials

What properties of wood make it useful for it to be in furniture?

Answer (score 2):

Wood was always a prime building material for tools, structures, furniture and so on.

For the most part, probably because there is or was so much of it. Also, its easy to work with. You can shape wood quite easy and good.

Its also hard but not brittle, so it can withstand some pressure/weight.

Also, it grows literally on trees.

Negative side of course, it burns rather good.

Comment: Splinters are a negative too!!